# Append a tuple to a list - what's the difference between two ways?

Tags: python, list, types, append, tuples

I wrote my first "Hello World" 4 months ago. Since then, I have been following a Coursera Python course provided by Rice University. I recently worked on a mini-project involving tuples and lists. There is something strange about adding a tuple into a list for me:

```
a_list = []
a_list.append((1, 2))       # Succeed! Tuple (1, 2) is appended to a_list
a_list.append(tuple(3, 4))  # Error message: ValueError: expecting Array or iterable
```

It's quite confusing for me. Why specifying the tuple to be appended by using "tuple(...)" instead of simple "(...)" will cause a `ValueError`?

BTW: I used `CodeSkulptor` [coding tool used in the course](http://www.codeskulptor.org/)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) function takes only one argument which has to be an iterable

> `tuple([iterable])`
>
> Return a tuple whose items are the same and in the same order as iterable‘s items.

Try making `3,4` an iterable by either using `[3,4]` (a list) or `(3,4)` (a tuple)

For example

```
a_list.append(tuple((3, 4)))
```

will work

Answer (score 24):

Because `tuple(3, 4)` is not the correct syntax to create a tuple. The correct syntax is -

```
tuple([3, 4])
```

or

```
(3, 4)
```

You can see it from here - https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with `append`.  `tuple(3, 4)` all by itself raises that error.

The reason is that, as the error message says, `tuple` expects an iterable argument.  You can make a tuple of the *contents* of a *single* object by passing that single object to tuple.  You can't make a tuple of two things by passing them as separate arguments.

Just do `(3, 4)` to make a tuple, as in your first example.  There's no reason not to use that simple syntax for writing a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `tuple()` takes a list as an argument
For example,

```
tuple([1,2,3]) # returns (1,2,3)
```

see what happens if you wrap your array with brackets

Answer (score 1):

There should be no difference, but your tuple method is wrong, try:

```
a_list.append(tuple([3, 4]))
```